# GIT public repo - verification for sensitive information

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, passwords

Is there any way that git can check committed code and give notification in case any sensitive information is available in the code (even if it is commented in the code, e.g., aws access/secret key pairs, connection strings, IPs etc).

At least for publically available repositories.

I think this may be a huge benefit if git will implement such verification.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You can use Git commit hooks to build this functionality yourself: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks If you search you will find some examples for doing exactly what you are wanting to do.

Comment: That should probably be a pre-commit hook though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it.

#### [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

git hooks is a script that run in a different phases of the git life-cycle.

#### [Smudge/clean](https://github.com/gilesbowkett/git-smudge-and-clean)

Basically, smudge is equivalent to **run this code whenever you check anything out**
and clean is equivalent to **run this code whenever you check anything in**.

---

Images are from this url:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes

[image]
[image]